# Segment Hand Image into Palm and Fingers

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, image-segmentation

Here is my code, i want to extract only the fingers and save them as a new image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def get_image():
global image
image = cv2.imread("testPalm.png", 0)

get_image()
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
ret, thresh_binary = cv2.threshold(image, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

thresh_binary = cv2.erode(thresh_binary, None, iterations=2)
thresh_binary = cv2.dilate(thresh_binary, None, iterations=2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh_binary, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE,   method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
min_width = 50
min_height = 50
filtered_contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.boundingRect(c)[2] > min_width and     cv2.boundingRect(c)[3] > min_height]
cv2.drawContours(image, filtered_contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow('All Contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried researching open cv, i know what i want to do but not how.

[image: Hand]

Comment: 1. the actual image you show is a quarter, not a hand; 2. you give a bunch of code, but that's just -- code.  Please _edit your question_ to show the correct image, and to describe your algorithm _in words_.  One of the important facets of signal processing is that the **very last thing you should care about** is what platform you do it on.  The _most important_ part is the techniques used to segment hand pixels from finger pixels.  The _least important part_ is the fact you're doing it using OpenCV and Python.

Comment: @TimWescott it has a full image with a hand

Answer (score 1):

You may use a MATLAB function [`bwgrowregions()`](https://github.com/WD40andTape/bwgrowregions) which is an open source code.

They actually show your case as an example:

[image]

If you're limited to Python + OpenCV, since the code is MIT Licensed you may have a look on the algorithm and replicate it.